# Error while installing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install `tensorflow` on cluster where I don't have sudo access, but I am receiving this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "/home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/nsoufi2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: It would help if you specify on which platform you are trying to install Tensorflow. The error you encouter is because the compiled tensorflow libraries are dynamically linked against glibc 2.14 and your platform does not support this.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a virtual environment in your home directory using the following commands. You will not need sudo access.

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
source activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

`conda install tensorflow` works